# How do I convert a 24-speed bike to a seven speed?

Tags: cassette, trek, 7-speed

I just recently posted another question about the same bike. This Trek that I am getting is a 24 speed and I want to convert it to a 7 speed so it's better rated for rough trails so I can go with my friends. If someone could help me out with this that would be great!

Comment: Do you fear a dropped chain? Or why do you want to do that?

Comment: I was reading up on bikes and which are best for rough trails. The best was 7-speed for rough trails. This is why I want to do it.

Comment: @James What's your source for that info? It might have been good advice in like, 1990.

Comment: https://www.sixthreezero.com/blogs/bike-advice/single-speed-bike-or-multi-speed#:~:text=If%20you%20prefer%20rougher%20terrain,a%2021%2Dspeed%20is%20best. this is my source

Comment: Between your last three posts, it sounds like everything's wrong with this bike.  If you're buying it for money, perhaps don't buy it?

Comment: I currently have a BMX bike and it's a size 20 so I want a bigger bike. I'm getting this bike for free and want to make it work well. So no I'm not spending money on it.

Comment: That site is, putting it very politely, not providing good advice. Suggest you get the bike into working condition then ride it for a while before doing anything to it. Its nearly 20 years old and entry level, so not worth spending money making it better.  If you want a better bike, ride that as is while you save money to buy one.

Comment: Okay. People keep telling me to ride it as is, so I'm going to do that. . .

Comment: That site sixthreezero is run by a bike brand, and is giving "advice" that encourages you to buy one of their bikes. It's not a balanced source of information.

Comment: Thank you. I'll keep that in mind for the future

Comment: @James Whoever runs that company has a good marketing degree, not an engineering one. It's a bunch of marketing BS catering towards ignorant (through no fault of their own), inexperienced first-time buyers. 21-speed and 7-speed bikes are really only understandable on $200 kids bikes nowadays.

Comment: Ok thank you MaplePanda!

Comment: @AdamRice it looked to me like it was put together as an exercise in creating a pretty website.  There's something a little unnatural about the language that makes it feel like filler text rather than real advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your bike is 3x8 you could convert it to 1x8 but you will loose a lot of gear range for a very dubious profit. If you are careful when shifting, you should not suffer too much from the front shifting.

In that case you will need a new 1x crankset with the right chainline, a narrow-wide chainring and most likely a chain guide. You probably won't find a clutch derailleur for those 8 speeds.

I would not go to 7 speed, keep it 8 speed.

Comment: ok thank you for your help

Answer (score 6):

1. I cannot imagine a good reason to do this. Your drivetrain will not be more robust.
2. Doing this will be fairly expensive. You'll need a new cassette (to go from 8 gears to 7) and new a new rear shifter (likewise). You'll probably want to leave the front derailleur in place to prevent the chain from unshipping, or replace it with a dedicated "chain watcher."
3. Your gearing range will be drastically reduced. Either hills are going to be a lot harder, or you'll be spinning out on the flats. Maybe both. Although there are 1× setups that cover wide gearing ranges, these are not available in 7-speed cassettes; if they were, the jumps between gears would be huge.

Comment: So you don't think this is a good idea?

Comment: It's not a good idea. I hope I made that clear.

Comment: You did. Thank you for the advice. I will leave it as a 24 speed.

Comment: There are downhill bikes that are 1×7, but you're relying on gravity to make them go. They're very specialized.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for your help

Comment: Technically, 7 and 8 speed cassettes have almost same cog spacing so you could get away with keeping the old shifter and derailleur. It would still not be a good idea.

Comment: Well, in fact one could even take apart the cassette and replace the largest cog with a spacer :)